# How to improve my "please edit the question" comments

Tags: discussion, edits, comments

How can I (or should I?) write comments to prompt editing of the post?

Generally, I write comments to request clarifications/improvements to questions strictly for warm fuzzies. Somewhat unfortunately sometimes people reply to such comments, but I almost never seen (nor expect) actual edits to happen as result. Today I got "thanks" with no edit reply to such comment - I'm not even sure what to make of it, to extent it feels even rude... Joking about flagging as rude aside, what, if anything, can be done to improve chances of people to actually edit posts instead of commenting as answer?

- I do include `[edit]` in the comment, so it is a link there
- I try to specify what needs to be added/clarified, usually with the `[mre]` link too

---

Sample exchange that triggered the post - Thanks as response with no edits to the post. The outcome is roughly the same irrespective of user's reputation/time on the site.

My comment as text (this is roughly how my comments of this type look like):

> Please re-read the minimal reproducible example guidance and edit post to include text instead of images - at very least for error message, but really list of files can be shown as text (`dir /s /b` is a good way to get text with folder names). While you are at it you may want to check if files actually can be found at locations mentioned in the error message.

Response:

> OK - I did not know - thank u Yes the files are there. I even tried to delete them and recreate from scratch (relaunch VS also) but nothing works

Comment: Ultimately, some horses are just not thirsty.

Comment: Honestly, the best thing you can do, if you think the question needs improving and isn't clear (or on-topic) without the edit, is vote to close. If it is clear and on-topic, then perhaps downvote. If you then want to comment to add further details on *how* they can improve the question, then you are free to do so. The carrot on the stick seems to be much bigger when a user's question is closed, as they *can't* get answers until they actually take the time. *I will admit, however, that adding "magic links" like `[edit]` doesn't do any harm, some users do "struggle" to find the feature.*

Comment: It's exceedingly common for somebody to post a bad question and then never respond to a single comment. That's a huge waste of everybody's time, including theirs. It's also quite common for people to take offense to objective, concise feedback. And then there's those who just don't read. In the end, anyone who writes things like "I tried X and it didn't work" do not have a firm grasp on the process of systematic troubleshooting and reporting. Helping them will be an uphill battle, accumulating extensive commentary and down-votes. Closing such questions early is the most pragmatic approach.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel They're thirsty. But they die. Lack of thirst is not the problem.

Comment: My only suggestion is to copy and paste the close reason, which indicates the question needs additional details; by copying and pasting the close reason, you are providing feedback (which many users claim they want), and the comment is clear enough to indicate what needs to happen for an answer to be submitted. You also avoid being accused of being rude, towards new users, since how can you possible be rude to a new users if you are copying and pasting something that is already displayed the user when their question is ultimately closed.

Comment: FWIW, [this is a comment I posted to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580785/netbeans-debugger-ignore-breakpoints#comment133394415_75580785) earlier today: _"Provide any new information for your question by updating it rather than using comments. It shouldn't be necessary to read the comments at all to fully understand your question."_. Explaining why you are asking someone to do something is more persuasive than just telling them. Consider downvoting the question later if they ignore you, and either way the comment reminds anyone reading it of the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to start such comments with "Please". However, it is mostly futile no matter how it is phrased (though guidelines are very welcome); the conversion rate is probably less than 1% (at least for late comments). Most users are accustomed to forum-like sites, not wiki-like sites.

Comment: I think you were talking to a wall so there is little you can do. But I think you put too much information in that comment. Baby steps.