# What is the preferred method for guiding newcomers to make their posts more presentable (grammar/spelling/formatting/etc)? Do it for them? Or comment?

Tags: discussion, new-users

In [How to parse the below Json data coming from Kafkatopic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75794850/how-to-parse-the-below-json-data-coming-from-kafkatopic), a new user asked a question with JSON code blocks on a single, very long line. Instead of just editing the question directly, I wanted to guide the new user into writing questions with better formatting, so I suggested to the asker to edit the question to include line breaks in the code blocks to make it more readable.

Later, someone else proposed an edit that basically did what I was asking.

The visible result is the same (the question is now readable), but I think the outcome is slightly different in that the user didn't necessarily learn anything about how to get the most out of the site.  The user may not understand why (or even notice that) the question was edited.

What is the preferred approach for this site?  Do we prefer guiding new users, or do we prefer immediate edits?

Comment: Why not both? Edit *and* point them to the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and/or [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or other resources.

Comment: What I said in my answer @VLAZ

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch I didn't propose an arbitrary time limit.

Comment: They aren't the exact thing, I just said I agree with you. I did add other stuff @VLAZ

Comment: It is safe to assume they will ***never*** improve on their initial post. It is futile to convert users. The conversion rate is much less than 1%, and it is not what we are here for anyway.

Comment: Somewhat related Q of mine about making comments - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423434/how-to-improve-my-please-edit-the-question-comments - comments are for "warm fuzzies" and not to get post improved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of right and wrong or preferred and not-preferred, I think either are okay and acceptable.

- In the review queues, there are dedicated review actions for editing and indicating that post could use edits from the rest of the community. (which indicates to me that such actions are good / desirable / commendable actions)
- [The comment privilege Help Center page](/help/privileges/comment) says you can comment to "*Request clarification from the author; Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;*".

So at the end of the day, I think how you behave here is up to you.

For efficiency's sake, it's usually faster in total time to edit things for post owners: You don't have to wait for them to see your comment and take action, and you don't leave behind any comments that are then no longer needed and either stick around all useless-like and maybe end up being flagged for removal. (And you don't have to worry about whether they will fix it up to your standards)

I like the idea of teaching users to make their posts presentable, and used to make such comments quite a bit. Recently I tend to just edit the post for them, or ignore it, or if I'm lazy and it's a really bad case, downvote it. Nobody has ever come after me for commenting asking a user to improve their formatting (except stubborn users who flagged those comments of mine as unfriendly, which unfortunately adds to plate of mods and not to me).

Once Staging Ground leaves beta, I think Staging Grounds is an excellent place to teach users to make these fixes themselves before approving their posts (though you can still do the fixes for them in Staging Grounds).